# Time complexity of sieve algorithm

Tags: python, time-complexity, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, sieve

Unlike the traditional sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
n=10000000
sieve = [True] * n
for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
    if sieve[i]:
        sieve[i*i::2*i]=[False]*((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
sieve=[2] + [i for i in range(3,n,2) if sieve[i]]
```

What is the time complexity of the following enhanced version?

```
n=10000000
sieve5m6 = [True] * (n//6+1)
sieve1m6 = [True] * (n//6+1)
for i in range(1,int((n**0.5+1)/6)+1):
    if sieve5m6[i]:
        sieve5m6[6*i*i::6*i-1]=[False]*((n//6-6*i*i)//(6*i-1)+1)
        sieve1m6[6*i*i-2*i::6*i-1]=[False]*((n//6-6*i*i+2*i)//(6*i-1)+1)
    if sieve1m6[i]:
        sieve5m6[6*i*i::6*i+1]=[False]*((n//6-6*i*i)//(6*i+1)+1)
        sieve1m6[6*i*i+2*i::6*i+1]=[False]*((n//6-6*i*i-2*i)//(6*i+1)+1)
sieve=[2,3] 
for i in range(1,int(n/6)+1):
    if sieve5m6[i]:
        sieve.append(6*i-1)
    if sieve1m6[i]:
        sieve.append(6*i+1)
```

Better version  with numpy array functions useful for n> 10 ^ 9:

```
def sieve(n):
    baseW=30
    baseP=np.array([-23,-19,-17,-13,-11,-7,-1,1])
    C=np.ones((len(baseP),len(baseP)), dtype=int)
    C1=np.zeros((len(baseP),len(baseP)), dtype=int)
    C=np.multiply(np.dot(np.diag(baseP),C),np.dot(C,np.diag(baseP)))
    C=C%baseW
    C[C>1] = C[C>1] -baseW
    for i in range(len(baseP))    :
        C1[i,:]=baseP[np.argwhere(C==baseP[i])[:,1]]
    primeB=np.ones((len(baseP),n//baseW+1), dtype=bool)
    for j in range(1,int((n**0.5-baseP[0])/baseW)+1):
        for i in range(len(baseP)):
            if primeB[i,j]:
                for i1 in range(len(baseP)):
                    j1=1-1*i1//(len(baseP)-1)+baseW*j*j+(baseP[i]+C1[i1,i])*j+np.dot(baseP[i],C1[i1,i])//baseW
                    primeB[i1,j1::(baseW*j+baseP[i])] =False
    return np.append([2,3,5],baseP[np.nonzero(primeB.T)[1][len(baseP):]]+baseW*np.nonzero(primeB.T)[0][len(baseP):])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity is the same.  The second version may perform faster because it skips more factors but the relationship to n in the same order of magnitude.

In other words you have O(f2) = K * O(f1) = O(f1) where K is a constant and unrelated to n.

If you want something that has a (slightly) better time complexity than the sieve of Eratosthenes, you may want to look at [the sieve of Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin), although it may not have better overall performance due to the higher cost of each iteration.

Comment: I edited the question to insert the code with a sieve to skip even more factors I don't understand the difference with the Atkin sieve I think the same number of elements are eliminated

Comment: According to the articles the sieve of Atkin has O(N) complexity whereas Eratosthenes's has O(N log log N).  This is related to the fact that Atkin's only flags multiples of the squares of prime numbers thus flagging 1/n of the factors proportionally.  This applies a *dependent* factor on the complexity level (as opposed to a fixed *independent* multiplier).

Comment: according to posts by user GordonBGood on SO the constant factor disadvantage drowns out the theoretical advantage in complexity and in any feasible range Atkin's is slower than  the fully optimized segmented Eratosthenes'.